# React requests with axios on DRF api throws error Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, csrf

This is my react Js code :

```
export function loginUser({ email, password }, history) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios({
      url: URL_LOGIN_BASE,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      // withCredentials: true,
      data: { "email": email, "password": password }
    }).then(response => {
      dispatch(setAuthentification(true));
      history.push("/dashboard");
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
}
```

And here my the server configuration (settings.py):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
        "localhost",
    "192.168.0.1",
    "mockbic.spnnjy4rjm.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com"
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
    '127.0.0.1:3000',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
    'mock-bic-token',  # IMPORTANT
)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "storages",
    "datacollection.apps.DatacollectionConfig",
    "corsheaders",
]
```

So i have the backend error : Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /

[backend error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKcQr.png)

Please this question is very current but all solutions tried don't resolve my case... Help !

Comment: Please add the text of your error in your question, don't add the image as it might be unavailable in the future and the text is easier to reference.

Comment: You Mention that all solutions tried don't resolve your case, could you add the ones you already tried to your question as well? This way, you can get better answers for your question, or else you will get solutions that you might have already tried.

Comment: I have used the "withCredentials=true", credentials: 'include' and add axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken"; bellow axios import but nothings resolve the problem

Comment: The error is : Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /
[11/Oct/2018 18:37:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 2868

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to add `csrf` token in your request headers.

```
export function loginUser({ email, password }, history) {
      return (dispatch) => {
      axios({
        url: URL_LOGIN_BASE,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "X-CSRFToken" : "TOKEN FROM YOUR COOKIES" 
        },
        // withCredentials: true,
        data: { "email": email, "password": password }
      }).then(response => {
        dispatch(setAuthentification(true));
        history.push("/dashboard");
        console.log(response);
     }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

// function below returns csrftoken from cookies.

```
  export const getCsrfToken = () => {
      const csrf = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*csrftoken\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
      return csrf ? csrf.pop() : '';
    };
```

Comment: Thank but it still don't work for me ! I set so : axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken"; but always the same backend response 403

Comment: i use csrf in my project. and i simply pass it in headers.. nothing in axios.defaults.xsrfCookiaName.. see my updated answer to get csrftoken from cookies

Comment: Ooops ! resolved... the URL was bad. After set it properly it work fine !!!